# How can i have something like SELECT id, (id in(2,3,4) ) as idIs234 from Messageset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I create such a query in sql server?

```
SELECT id, (id in(2,3,4) ) as idIs234 from Messageset
```

I want a result like

```
id idIs234 
-----------
1 false
2 true
3 true
4 true
5 false
6 false
```

This code doesn't work, but I hope there is an alternative which I don't know.

Comment: yes, I just updated the question.. I don't know how to make it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEexample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf41b/2)**

```
SELECT 
id,
CASE WHEN id in(2,3,4) 
      THEN 'TRUE'
      ELSE 'FALSE'
  END AS ids
FROM Messageset
```

Result:

```
| ID |   IDS |
--------------
|  1 | FALSE |
|  2 |  TRUE |
|  3 |  TRUE |
|  4 |  TRUE |
|  5 | FALSE |
|  6 | FALSE |
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CASE` statement:

```
select id,
  case when id in (2,3,4) then 'true' else 'false' end result
from Messageset
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1b8ef/1)

Result:

```
| ID | RESULT |
---------------
|  1 |  false |
|  2 |   true |
|  3 |   true |
|  4 |   true |
|  5 |  false |
|  6 |  false |
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what database server you're using, and there is no a standard way of doing that, so I'll give you how you can do it with MySQL, using an [`IF function`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) , like this:

```
SELECT id, IF(id IN ( 2, 3, 4 ) ,  'true',  'false' ) AS idIs234
FROM Messageset
```

Comment: `CASE` is the standard way of doing that.

Comment: @hvd yeah - that's what's what I did .. assuming it's not a hardcoded list.

Answer (score 1):

#### Assumption - the 2,3,4 are NOT a hardcoded list .. but just a simple example of a short list.

The other solutions have a hardcoded check for `2, 3 or 4`. I'm assuming that you have a short list .. so I'm highlighting how you can check for `NULL` if you do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

```
-- Setup the subquery / sub table.
-- In this case, it's a variable table.
DECLARE @TempData TABLE (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO @TempData VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @TempData VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO @TempData VALUES (4)

-- Outer join the two tables. If there's no join, then the second table 
-- will be NULL.
SELECT a.Id AS Id, 
    CASE WHEN b.Id IS NULL THEN 'False' 
        ELSE 'True' END 
        AS Idls234
FROM [dbo].[Messageset] a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @TempData b ON a.Id = b.Id
```

Fixed up via help from [hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd).

See [Sql Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1b8ef/5)

Comment: This should be `CASE WHEN b.Id IS NULL THEN ...`. What you have now is a workable approach, but it tests `b.Id = NULL`, which is never true. Nor is it false, but the `ELSE` expression will still be picked.

Comment: thanks mate :) fixed (and i didn't know about Sql Fiddle, either! Woot!)

Answer (score 0):

OK now

```
SELECT id, 
case when id in(2,3,4) then 'true'
else 'false'
end idIs234 from Messageset
```

Comment: maybe you could elaborate around your statement *"ok now"*, it's a little short.